# how to convert a string to a vertex in a graph?

Tags: graph, jung

I'm trying to run hits algororithm of jung library. The input of this algorithm is a graph, so I created ones and I use it as an input of this algorithm. But when I run it, Eclipse generate this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
cannot be cast to edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Vertex
at com.tweets.algorithms.HITS.initialize(HITS.java:52)
at com.tweets.algorithms.HITS.<init>(HITS.java:41)
at com.tweets.test.Main.main(Main.java:121)
```

Here is how I created my graph:

```
private static String getId(int nodeId){
     return "Node " + nodeId;
}



private static String getId(int nodeId, int neighborId){
        return "Edge " + nodeId + " -> " + neighborId;
}



public static Graph<String, Integer> createGraph1(String graphId,
                                              boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix){
    Graph<String,Integer> g = new DirectedSparseGraph <String,Integer>();

    for (int nodeId = 0; nodeId < adjacencyMatrix.length; nodeId++)
         g.addVertex(getId(nodeId));


    for (int nodeId = 0; nodeId < adjacencyMatrix.length; nodeId++)
        for (int neighborId = 0; neighborId < adjacencyMatrix[nodeId].length; neighborId++)
            if (adjacencyMatrix[nodeId][neighborId])
                 //g.addEdge(getId(nodeId, neighborId),nodeId , neighborId);
                   g.addEdge(neighborId,getId(nodeId),getId(neighborId));

                   return(g);

           }
```

And this is how I call the hits algorithm in the main class:

```
HITS ranker = new HITS(g);
                 ranker.evaluate();
                ranker.printRankings(true,false);
```

And the IDE indicated that the error is in this bloc in the hits class:

```
protected void initialize(Graph g) {

        super.initialize(g, true, false);

        mPreviousAuthorityScores = new HashMap();
        mPreviousHubScores = new HashMap();

        for (Iterator vIt = g.getVertices().iterator(); vIt.hasNext();) {
            Vertex currentVertex = (Vertex) vIt.next();
            setRankScore(currentVertex, 1.0, AUTHORITY_KEY);
            setRankScore(currentVertex, 1.0, HUB_KEY);

            mPreviousAuthorityScores.put(currentVertex, new MutableDouble(0));
            mPreviousHubScores.put(currentVertex, new MutableDouble(0));
        }
    }
```

I'm sure that's a cast error, but I can't resolve it.
Can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have two incompatible versions of JUNG in your classpath: one that's using generics (e.g. Graph) which makes it version 2.x, and one that is using the old-style Vertex interfaces, which is version 1.x.

You need to remove the version 1.x version from your classpath.

Comment: I have jar's that come from JUNG 1.7.6 and other ones that come from JUNG 2.0.1 , wich ones should I remove.

Comment: Joshua O'Madadhain can you please give a link from I can download a version of JUNG that contains all necessary Jar's for JUNG.

Comment: Another thing, please Joshua O'Madadhain, can you give me also a link from wich I can download the HITS.class. I'm using this one. IS this the rignt code?

Comment: http://logic.cse.unt.edu/tarau/teaching/GraphTheory/jung/OLD/jung/src/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/importance/HITS.java

Comment: @Amira, as I said above, you should remove the version 1.x (in your case, 1.7.6) from your classpath.

Comment: @Amira no, that is not the place where you should get the JUNG source.  For now, the canonical source of JUNG is here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/files/jung/jung-2.0.1/ (home page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/)

Comment: but I want to change the initial values of hub and authority scores that are set to 1 with others values. I don't know in wich part of the code I should manahe them. I tryied to find an initialization in HITS.java, HITSWithPriors.java and many other class in the package edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.scoring that are related to the class HITS.java but I failed.Can you please help me?

Comment: You should have no real reason to care what the initial values are as long as they're a valid probability distribution.  Why do you want to change them?

Comment: I want to change them because I use yhe algorithm to manipulate sentences and words( for me they are vertex) and I want to change initial values because I have to put the initial value of a hub into occrences of the words in a sentences and authority into similarity between sentences and the query

Comment: in the old version of the algorithm it seems to be simple to manage them in this bloc of code:

Comment: protected void initialize(Graph g) {
 
        super.initialize(g, true, false);
 
        mPreviousAuthorityScores = new HashMap();
        mPreviousHubScores = new HashMap();
 
        for (Iterator vIt = g.getVertices().iterator(); vIt.hasNext();) {
            Vertex currentVertex = (Vertex) vIt.next();
            setRankScore(currentVertex, 1.0, AUTHORITY_KEY);
            setRankScore(currentVertex, 1.0, HUB_KEY);
 
            mPreviousAuthorityScores.put(currentVertex, new MutableDouble(0));
            mPreviousHubScores.put(currentVertex, new MutableDouble(0));
        }
    }

Comment: The whole point of eigenvalue-based (or random-walk-based) measures like HITS is that the answer you get once the scores have converged is independent of the input distributions; it's a function only of the transition probabilities.  If you want to manipulate the initial distribution for some reason (e.g. because you believe it will converge faster from your specified starting point) then you will need to do some hacking on AbstractIterativeScorer.

Comment: If you have further questions, please start a new post; this one's wandered quite a lot from the post topic.  :)